# How to remove flat list padding on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want the horizontal padding of the flat list closer to the edge of the screen so that the image will be shown. . Is there anyway that can be done?

This is the current of what i have

[image]

This is what i'm trying to achieve
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try settting the contentContainerStyle prop

```
<Flatlist contentContainerStyle={{paddingLeft: 50}}/>
```

Comment: I tried adding 15 on paddingLeft but it still leaves me with gap between the flatlist and the screen edge https://prnt.sc/adbW2wQCInkm @eeshankeni, i wanted it to be edge to edge with the left screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this should be a problem.
Check out my [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/flatlist-example-no-border):

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

import {
  FlatList,
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

const dummyArray = [
  { id: '1', value: 'A' },
  { id: '2', value: 'B' },
  { id: '3', value: 'C' },
  { id: '4', value: 'D' },
  { id: '5', value: 'E' },
  { id: '6', value: 'F' },
  { id: '7', value: 'G' },
  { id: '8', value: 'H' },
  { id: '9', value: 'I' },
  { id: '10', value: 'J' },
  { id: '11', value: 'K' },
  { id: '12', value: 'L' },
  { id: '13', value: 'M' },
  { id: '14', value: 'N' },
  { id: '15', value: 'O' },
  { id: '16', value: 'P' },
  { id: '17', value: 'Q' },
  { id: '18', value: 'R' },
  { id: '19', value: 'S' },
];

const App = () => {
  const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(dummyArray);

  const ItemView = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', borderWidth: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ borderLeftWidth: 1, borderColor: '#ff00ff' }} />
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.item} onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
            {item.value}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };


  const getItem = (item) => {
    //Function for click on an item
    alert('Id : ' + item.id + ' Value : ' + item.value);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={2}
        data={listItems}
        renderItem={ItemView}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
});

export default App;
```